# How can I host my own website

Tags: dns, webserver, hosting

I have bought a domain lets say it example.com, I also own an Ubuntu 10.04 machine which I would like to use it to serve my personal website. I have deployed the website on my local machine and its set with a static IP address which I can access like http://xx.xx.xx.xx

What I would like to do is connect my domain name example.com so it points to my ip in order to serve the page.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this static IP you claim to have a 192.168.x.x address, or a 10.x.x.x address?

Comment: its a public static ip like 77.50.60.12 not the internal ones.

Comment: ah, very good.  wanted to make sure it was actually static xD

Comment: Try looking into this [link](http://thevoidghost.wordpress.com/2011/06/09/accessing-your-local-web-server-files-apache2tomcat6-from-an-external-network-in-linux-how-to-especially-on-a-beetel-220bxi-modem/) It MAY give you an idea as to what needs to be done.

Comment: [This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9686/what-is-the-most-rampant-duplicate-on-stack-exchange-sites/50116#50116) might be a good resource for you.

Comment: you guys realize he was trying to get his domain name to point to his server, right?  He needed a DNS server around, he decided to use a free one (i know this because he and i talked in teh au chat)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start by modifying your domain's DNS settings in the registrar's control panel and provide the nameserver as the static IP you claim to have.  Doing this (then waiting approximately 24 hours for DNS to update worldwide) should then allow you to type in the domain and get to your site under the following conditions:
   (a) The system is web facing, and your firewall has been configured to allow port 80 traffic to reach your system, or
   (b) Port 80 (the normal HTTP port) has been opened in the NAT'd gateway that may exist between your system and the actual internet connection (for example, a router that forwards port 80 to your machine), and the same port has also been allowed in your computer's firewall.

Comment: My host master keeps throwing me a message when I am trying to pass my ip as a nameserver. How can I map my ip into something like ns1.iamcool.com?

Comment: @Chris-Top you'd need to use a DNS services provider, then.  I'd recommend zoneedit, or another free DNS service provider, because your ISP may be looking for an actual DNS records server to be at the location (hence how the system processes records).  First, you should make sure you're familiar with how DNS works.  I dont have a link to any reference material at the moment though.

Comment: @Chris-Top I'm actually in the AU chat rooms fairly often, if you want to discuss this further, find me there, esp. if you need some real-time assistance.  I run one site off of 3 different servers, so I'm relatively familiar with the basic setup steps.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add an 'A' record to the DNS Nameserver for your domain that points to the IP address of your external internet connection.

You must make sure that you have a static external IP address. If you are using NAT on your router you will also need to make sure you add a Port Forwarding rule to forward anything coming in on port 80 to your server.

That will get the traffic going to your server.

You will then need to add your domain to the apache config file ( httpd.conf ). If you want to host more than one site you will need to switch on namebased virtual hosts

Comment: Not necessary if the system only hosts one site.  If they want more than one site, then they will need to modify the config files.

Comment: I have done my research about setting virtual hosts, and thanks for the info, but my issue is I can't go global, everything else from there its pretty much set up.